# Distribution of charge in series capacitor arrangement

Tags: charge, capacitance

If I have 3 capacitors in series connected as shown- C1=C2=C3=C)[image]

And let a charge 'Q' is on all 3 capacitors.
Then if a question is asked **'What is total charge in the circuit?**'
Why '3Q' is the wrong answer while 'Q' is correct.

A reasoning could be that when a equivalent circuit is drawn it has Q charge with $C_{eq}$ as Capacitance. But still i think that if we drain the above arrangment represented in the figure through the resistor, wouldn't a total of 3Q charge will pass,until the capacitors are completely discharged, Q from each capacitor, thus total charge should be 3Q.

I have seen similar question on the site but my main confusion is '*if we drain the above arrangment represented in the figure through the resistor, wouldn't a total of 3Q charge will pass,until the capacitors are completely discharged, Q from each capacitor'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you've charged up your combination so that there is charge $+Q$ on the leftmost electrode of C<sub>1</sub> and $-Q$ on the rightmost electrode of C<sub>3</sub>.

In the diagram you've drawn, there are two electrically neutral "islands" that charge cannot move on or off of.

- One consists of the right-hand electrode of C<sub>1</sub> (carrying $-Q$), the left-hand electrode of C<sub>2</sub> (carrying $+Q$), and the wire connecting them.
- The other consists of the right-hand electrode of C<sub>2</sub> (carrying $-Q$), the left-hand electrode of C<sub>3</sub> (carrying $+Q$), and the wire connecting them.

If you were to charge up the combination of capacitors as you describe, and then discharge it through the resistor, none of the charges on these "islands" would flow through the resistor.  They can't, because those "islands" are not connected by conducting paths to the rest of the circuit.  As the capacitors discharge, the charge distribution on the "islands" re-equilibrate, as some of the electrons on the right-hand electrodes move back over to the left-hand electrodes.  But no electrons ever jump the gaps between the capacitor plates.

Only the electrons on the rightmost electrode of C<sub>3</sub> can flow through the resistor.  And so the net charge that flows in the discharging process is $Q$, not $3Q$.

Comment: Definitely understood that. So basically i can say the charges on the extreme left and right plates were, in a way, supporting/responsible for the charge build up on the 'islands' but as soon as they drained through the wire, the charges on the 'island' collapsed. Is this the gist of the answer? Though i see that you explained in detail how this happens.

Comment: @AmitRai:  Yes, you've got it right.

Comment: @AmitRai I would avoid the term 'collapse'. It just redistribute differently. In a way the outermost plates are pushing and pulling the charges on the respectively facing plates via electrostatic induction. It's easier to imagine when you have only two caps in series, so that you can see it as an electron mist that is displaced with respect to the fixed ions. As you reduce the absolute value of the charge in the outer plate, you reduce the push and pull so that this 'electron cloud' realigns with the lattice making the isle uniformly neutral again. (It's a pictorial view, but I think it helps)